# got an error invalid argument=value of '0' is not valid for SelectedIndex' parameter name:Selectedindex

Tags: .net, vb.net

How can i filter my combobox display if my `Label.text ="ad"`, i want to display only those who have "ad" on database and shouldn't display all.
but  an error invalid argument=value of '0' is not valid for SelectedIndex' parameter name:Selectedindex "appear".

```
Private Sub FillCombo()
   Try
       conn = New OleDbConnection(Get_Constring)

       Dim sSQL As String = ("SELECT subject FROM student where subject like'" & Label25.Text & "%' ")
       Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(sSQL, conn)

       Dim ds As New DataSet
       da.Fill(ds)

       cmbsection.ValueMember = "subject"
       cmbsection.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
       cmbsection.SelectedIndex = 0

   Catch ex As Exception
       MsgBox("ERROR : " & ex.Message.ToString)
   End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure your query is actually returning results? If the cmbsection control has 0 items, then you cannot set your SelectedIndex to the first item.

Comment: what should be the appropriate code for this.

Comment: I'll also add that your application has a textbook [SQL Injection attack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx) vulnerability.

Comment: This question is only about a typo and serves no use beyond this single situation.

Comment: yes, that's what they said :) but since i dont have any basic or standard for coding in short i dont really know what is sql attack. well, i appreciate your concern :)

Comment: There was a link in that comment to an article addressing SQL Injection attacks and what to do about them.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim sSQL As String = ("SELECT subject FROM student where **username** like'" & Label25.Text & "%' ")

solved :)
```